# Is there a way to access local User Certificate Store from .Net Blazor web application?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, webassembly, blazor

I cant load user certificate within web assembly (Blazor web app).
Here is my code (it's modified example "Get Started with Blazor").

```
 ...added strings to _ViewImports.cshtml:
@using System.Security.Cryptography;
@using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
@using System.Security;
...


@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<p>Cert Name: @cname</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@functions {
int currentCount = 0;
string cname = "";
public X509Certificate2 UserCert;

void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
    UserCert = selectCert();
    cname = UserCert?.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);
}

public X509Certificate2 selectCert() 
{
    X509Certificate2 certSelected = null;
    try
    {
        X509Store x509Store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection col = x509Store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)col.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
        if (fcollection.Count > 0)
        {
            certSelected = fcollection[0];
        }
        x509Store.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cname = ex.Message;
    }
    return certSelected;
}

}
```

But it fails with exception message "Store MY doesn't exist" or smth. So, I just want to access user certificate store to make digital signatures etc. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean the local on the client machine?

Comment: I believe you can only do what the browser permits and reading the cert is not one of them

Comment: I mean on client machine of course. I believe some settings for browser permission exists, isn't it?

Comment: when using activex CapiCom (long long time ago), IE loaded user certs without any problem.

Comment: The store MY is user specific, depends an what user account is running the application pool. Modify your code to use the MACHINE store, it will give you less problems and is easier to manage. Also consider using only the storelocation consfructor

Comment: and just so you know. blazor is an experimental project. Its not going to be production ready anytime soon

Comment: OK, I understand. So, only one purpose of Web Assembly is javascript replacing for Visual Studio that's all?

Comment: Web Assembly is a language or rather a Bytecode compiled to run on a virtual machine along side JavaScript. You can compile C, C++, C#, etc. into Web Assembly, and run them in the Browser. Visual Studio is an application. As far as I know, it is mostly written in C#.

Comment: <b>Issac<b>OK. Can I use this perfect technology to digitally sign/verify data in client browser (*any browser if possible) ? No server-side key storage, noo other tricks, just Windows crypto API.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: Samuel Rizzon No. Only way to achieve this is local proxy-server with all crypto-stuff inside.

Comment: @IvanIvanov Did you manage to solve this in the end? :)  I will face the same issue in my next project :)

Comment: @keykey76
It's impossible due to security model of modern browsers and requires client-side browser-specific plugin like ActiveX CapiCom plugin for IE. Latest ttrends in this scope is local proxy server which handles all crypto ops. Cheers.

Comment: @IvanIvanov Thanks. I suspected security model of a browser would prohibit such operations. But what exactly do you mean by saying that a local proxy server could be a solution here? How?

Comment: @keykey76 I don't know how it solved in the rest of the world, but in Russia we have like this. After MS closed IE support, solution is to make small program acts as usual HTTPS proxy-server locally, and interacts with local key storage media (file, smart-card, flash drive etc) to provide crypto operations. Browser (any browser, no plugins required) is set up for use this proxy server. When  proxy application sees that user goes to specific site - it intercepts user's request, cry[ting/signing them, then sends to server, and vice versa. Of course, remote server must be set for this. Cheers.